# Get variable data outside from the Switch Statement in PHP

Tags: php

In my code I have a variable assign of some data inside a switch statement. But that variable not output the data when it calls outside the switch statement. Sample code is here.

```
switch (some condition){
   case 1:
   $userid = $receiver->getMessage();
   break;
   case 2:
   break;
 }

 echo $userid;
```

how I solve this problem.

Comment: Probably it enter in case 2, have you tried to echo condition before the switch statement?

Comment: `if(isset($userid)) echo $userid;` <- like this?

Comment: this code would absolutely work and echo the result of `$receiver->getMessage()`. You are sure that method returnes something?

Comment: @Jeff: This code 'works'. Just returns a notice when `condition !== 1`. If `condition === 1`, it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable declared inside `switch` statement is visible outside, of course.

Problem is when isn't declared inside switch, you can avoid it two ways:

1. `$userid = 'default value';` before `switch`
2. `echo isset($userid) ? $userid : 'default value';` after `switch`.

Default value can be whatever, if nothing, use empty string.

Answer (score 0):

On possible way is to declare the variable before you call the switch statement.

```
$userid = "";
switch (some condition){
   case 1:
   $userid = $receiver->getMessage();
   break;
   case 2:
   break;
 }

 echo $userid;
```

Answer (score -1):

You're not doing anything with case 2 *or* default. If you structure it like this, then it should work.

```
switch ($condition) {
  case 1:
     $userId = $receiver->getMessage();
  break;
  case 2:
     $userId = $receiver->someOtherMessage();
  break;
  default:
     $userId = null;
  break;
}
```

At a different point you can validate if the userId has actually been set as well.

Comment: When you use `default`, you can remove first line in your code.

Comment: True, I can remove it from the example.